# Hashmap can't loop - getKey() method not found - Using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

Hi I'm using Java 8 and I'm trying to create a filtered map of `cMap` that is filtered so that only the keys that exist in `outerTable` list are there... can anyone tell me why

```
public List<String> outerTables = ArrayList<String>() = {{ add("table1"); }}

private Map<String, List<String>> cMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

...(Do stuff to populate `cMap` with elements of `<String, List<String>>`)

```
Map<String, List<String>> cTempMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(cMap);

cMap.clear();

cMap.put(cTempMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(x -> outerTables.contains(x.getKey()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.getKey(), m -> m.getValue())));
```

is throwing the error...

```
Cannot resolve method 'getKey()'
```

I'm trying to follow the examples here - https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-loop-a-map-in-java/ and my syntax looks the same. Thanks.

Comment: what exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: To create a filtered map of cMap that is filtered so that only the keys that exist in outerTable list are there

Comment: would be better to add that to the post.

Comment: why would you attempt to add the filtered results back into the same map you've just filtered?

Comment: Because I am reusing the variable in other places and have already emptied it.  It wouldn't be causing this error anyway right

Comment: you're looking for `putAll` not `put`.

Comment: Ah. weird error message since `getKey()` is inside the `collect()` method. Why don't you leave an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're using `put` whereas you're supposed to use `putAll`.

Yes, the error is not very meaningful as it's saying "Cannot resolve method 'getKey()'".

```
 cMap.putAll(cMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> outerTables.contains(x.getKey()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.getKey(), m -> m.getValue())));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it (with merthod reference):

```
List<String> outerTables = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, List<String>> cMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
Map<String, List<String>> cTempMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(cMap);
cMap.putAll(cTempMap.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(x -> outerTables.contains(x.getKey()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                     Entry::getKey,
                                    Entry::getValue
                    )));
```

Comment: Why `Object::toString` instead of `Entry::getKey`? I suppose he does not want to change the keys by calling `toString` on the original keys.

Comment: my bad, its enty::get key, it s a bad copy past :( thanks for your comment, i changed it